# Can I change the output path format of Flink Streaming File Sink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I'm using Pyflink and the Streaming API to sync data into the file system. The path of the output files were like:

```
-2023-01-28--01
 |-part-xxx-0.json
-2023-01-28--03
 |-part-xxx-0.json
```

It seems the output file path format is `{year}-{month}-{day}--{hour}/part-xxx-{commit}.json`. How can I change the path format to such as `{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/part-xxx-{commit}.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom class extends DateTimeBucketAssigner and override the path generation logic in the getBucketId method

Here's an example - saving to a path with a prefix as the POJO class name:

```
public class DateTimeWithClassPrefixBucketAssigner<IN> extends DateTimeBucketAssigner {
....
    @Override
    public String getBucketId(Object element, Context context) {
        if (dateTimeFormatter == null) {
            dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatString).withZone(zoneId);
        }
        String prefix = element.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return prefix + "/" + dateTimeFormatter.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(context.currentProcessingTime()));
    }
}
```

End covert data format

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
...
    String input = "2022-01-31--10";
    String output = new SimpleDateFormat("{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/part-xxx.json").format(
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd--HH").parse(input)
```

Comment: How about using Python API? I didn't find this in Python API